# Plaintext password in NetworkCredential() .Net VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, webclient, networkcredentials

I have the following function that I'm calling from console application which I run on my computer locally:

```
Private Sub goNGetIt()
        Dim remoteUri As String = "https://url"
        Dim fileName As String = "C:\"
        Dim username As String
        Dim pass As String = Nothing
        Dim key As ConsoleKeyInfo

        Console.WriteLine("Enter username: ")
        username = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter password: ")
        key = Console.ReadKey(True)
        Do While key.Key <> ConsoleKey.Enter
            If key.Key <> ConsoleKey.Backspace Then
                pass = pass + key.KeyChar
                Console.Write("*")
            Else
                Console.Write("\b")
            End If
            key = Console.ReadKey(True)
        Loop
        Console.WriteLine()

        Dim cred As New NetworkCredential(username, pass)
        Dim myStringWebResource As String = Nothing

        Dim myWebClient As New WebClient()
        myWebClient.Credentials = cred

        myStringWebResource = remoteUri
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading File ""{0}"" from ""{1}"" ......." + ControlChars.Cr + ControlChars.Cr, fileName, myStringWebResource)

        Try
            myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, fileName)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded file ""{0}"" from ""{1}""", fileName, myStringWebResource)

    End Sub
```

I basically call this function to download a file locally, then process it, and move it into a database (located in another method).

I can't use securestring, since the server that I'm sending the request to won't accept them, and I have no control over it.

My question is this: Once my request is out on the wire, its wrapped in SSL, should it matter that the password was plaintext?

Also, if there is room for improvement in this process, I would love to hear it.

Thanks for the assistance in advance.

Comment: There's always a risk when sending passwords in plaintext, but since you state that you cannot change how the server is implemented (and the server expects the password in plaintext) you don't have that many options, right?

Comment: Do you have control over the user's password creation? If so then when the user creates the password you could encrypt to a hash and send the hash as plain text to the server so that the user's password isn't actually "birthdayc4k3" but rather a big long hash in the server's credential database. It's still sending plaintext but at least if someone is watching and they see that they'll think it's encrypted at first glance.

Comment: Do you know where I would look in a trace of the request to see if I was sending the password in plaintext?